# Error in Parameterized query for Search Input

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to make a single text input search option. I am getting the following error on cmd.Execute

Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 error '80040e10'
No value given for one or more required parameters.

Any suggestions?

```
searchQuery = Request.Form("searchQuery")

Set RSSearch= Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

strSQL = "SELECT ProductID, Description, LDescription FROM Products WHERE ProductID LIKE ? OR Description LIKE ? OR LDescription LIKE ?"
searchQuery = "%" & searchQuery & "%"  '' Add wildcards for partial matching

Dim cmd
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandText = strSQL

cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@searchQuery", adVarChar, adParamInput, 200, searchQuery)

Set RSSearch= cmd.Execute
```

Comment: You have 3 required parameters (`?`) but you only define 1 parameter, so the issue is as the error describes, you're missing at least 2 defined parameters. In fact, the only parameter you have defined is the one value that isn't an actual "parameter".

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Actually, we are checking only one searchQuery=Request.Form("searchQuery") value against all three fields ProductID, Description, LDescription in the database. 
Should I define them with the same parameter value that is "searchQuery". ANd should I remove CreateParameter "@searchQuery" I added above?

Comment: In that case you need to append the parameter 3 times as each `?` requires a parameter definition.